# Change project from MXML to AS error

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air, blackberry-playbook

I am trying to change a Flex mobile application using MXML to describe views, to one which uses AS3 to create the views. I changed:

**BEFORE: Assessments.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:MobileApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                 xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"     firstView="view.LoginView">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
</s:MobileApplication>`
```

**AFTER: Assessments.as**

```
package {
import spark.components.MobileApplication;
import view.LoginView;

[SWF(height="600", width="1024", frameRate="30", backgroundColor="#FFFFFF")]
public class Assessments extends MobileApplication{

    public function Assessments(){
        super();
        super.firstView = view.LoginView;
    }
}
}
```

However, now I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor.
at mx.preloaders::Preloader/initialize()[E:\dev\hero_private_beta\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\preloaders\Preloader.as:258]
at mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::initialize()[E:\dev\hero_private_beta\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:1977]
at mx.managers::SystemManager/initHandler()[E:\dev\hero_private_beta\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2479]
```

I believe it may be something to do with the Namespaces not being set in the .as version? Any ideas?

---

**UPDATE**

```
package view
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import net.airpoint.northgate.ui.components.AirpointNumericTextField;
import qnx.events.QNXApplicationEvent;
import qnx.system.QNXApplication;
import spark.components.Button;
import spark.components.Form;
import spark.components.FormHeading;
import spark.components.FormItem;
import spark.components.Label;
import spark.components.TextInput;
import spark.components.View;

public class LoginView extends View
{
    private var form:Form;

    private var usernameLabel:Label;
    private var usernameField:AirpointNumericTextField;
    private var passwordLabel:Label;
    private var passwordField:TextInput;
    private var submit:Button;

//  public var menu:AirpointAppMenu;

    public function LoginView()
    {

//      menu = new AirpointAppMenu();
//      QNXApplication.qnxApplication.addEventListener(QNXApplicationEvent.SWIPE_DOWN, showAppMenu);
        initializeUI();
    }

    public function showAppMenu(event:QNXApplicationEvent):void{
//      menu.show();

    }

    public function initializeUI():void{

        form = new Form();
        this.submit = new Button();
        this.submit.label = "Login...";
        form.defaultButton = this.submit;

        // Heading
        var fh:FormHeading = new FormHeading();
        fh.label = "Login";
        form.addElement(fh);

        // Username
        this.usernameField = new AirpointNumericTextField();
        var f1:FormItem = new FormItem();
        f1.label = "Username";
        f1.addElement(this.usernameField);

        // Password
        this.passwordField = new TextInput();
        this.passwordField.displayAsPassword =true;
        var f2:FormItem = new FormItem();
        f2.label = "Password";
        f2.addElement(this.passwordField);

        form.addElement(f1);
        form.addElement(f2);
        form.addElement(this.submit);
        this.addElement(form);

    }
}
}
```

[image]

---

**Update 3**
**AssessmentsApp.as**

```
package  {
import mx.events.FlexEvent;
import mx.styles.CSSStyleDeclaration;

import spark.components.Group;
import spark.components.MobileApplication;

import views.AssessmentsAppHome;

[SWF(height="600", width="1024", frameRate="30", backgroundColor="#000")]
public class AssessmentsApp extends MobileApplication{

    public function AssessmentsApp(){
        super();
        this.addEventListener(FlexEvent.APPLICATION_COMPLETE, onAppComplete);
    }

    private function onAppComplete(e:FlexEvent):void
    {
        this.removeEventListener(FlexEvent.APPLICATION_COMPLETE, onAppComplete);
        firstView = views.AssessmentsAppHome;
    }
}
}
```

**AssessmentsAppHome.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Home">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:VGroup>
    <s:TextInput text="awdwdawd"/>
</s:VGroup>
</s:View>
```

**Error**

**Preloader.as (Fails on displayClass = new... )**

```
// Create a new instance of the display class and attach it to the stage
    if (showDisplay)
    {
        displayClass = new displayClassName(); 
        // Listen for when the displayClass no longer needs to be on the stage
        displayClass.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,                                     displayClassCompleteHandler);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should extend `Sprite` (not `MobileApplication`). See [the following link](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/25068/Create_a_Flash_project_FB45_1397366_11.jsp).

Comment: Not if he wants to use Views.

Comment: But how do I then set the "firstView"? As firstview is not a property of sprite

Comment: Ye seen, page hadn't refreshed haha

Comment: Dead link. Please provide more context within SO next time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
package {
import spark.components.MobileApplication;
import view.LoginView;

[SWF(height="600", width="1024", frameRate="30", backgroundColor="#FFFFFF")]
public class Assessments extends MobileApplication{

    public function Assessments(){
        super();
        this.addEventListener(FlexEvent.APPLICATION_COMPLETE, onAppComplete);
    }

private function onAppComplete(e:FlexEvent):void
{
this.removeEventListener(FlexEvent.APPLICATION_COMPLETE, onAppComplete);
firstView = LoginView;
}
}
```

It could be that your ViewNavigator isn't instantiated yet when trying to access it in the constructor.

Comment: Hum, I think the problem is your LoginView class.  Try replacing `firstView = LoginView` with `firstView = Group` or something.  Post up `LoginView` as well.

Comment: Does it work if you remove everything within the class (event the constructor)?  Are you including any kind of weird libraries?

Comment: Ye Im including a small library to create a menu, Im guessing its something to do with that, going to create my own menu instead... cheers

Comment: Yeah, try removing the menu library from your project for now and see if it works.  It has been known that if you don't use proper flex instantiation procedures, some stuff can get screwy.  Or even not having the updated namespace in a Flex 3 library can do this.

Comment: removed the library all together and all references... still gettin error, so so so annoying and weird. going to start again.........

Comment: Clean your project or try on a new project.  This shouldn't be giving you an error.

Comment: still getting problems even after creating a new project with just 2 files, see updated post